# Responsive CSS - Issues w/ making divs responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm not sure exactly what issue I am having. I don't understand why the div containing the nav and the footer stay where I want them, but the div holding the main does not. How can I improve the responsiveness of the page? This is my first attempt at creating a webpage where everything is contained within divs. Is there a better way to design a responsive page. Also, do I have the media queries set up properly? I'm trying to learn how to use the Chrome Dev Tools to create media queries for most device sizes.

```css
body {
    font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; /* styles the font of the entire page */
    margin: 0px; /* removes empty space from around the webpage */
    text-transform: capitalize; /* the text is automatically capitalized */
}

#nav, #main, #footer {
    position: absolute; /* positions the three divs that make up the document */
}

#nav {
    background-color: #393e46; /* colors the background of the nav */
    left: 0; /* stretches the nav across the screen by removing space from the left side */
    right: 0; /* stretches the nav across the screen by removing space from the right side */
    text-align: right; /* aligns the links in the nav to the right */
}

#nav-container {
    margin: 0 auto; /* adds margins to both sides of the div, centers the div containing all the other divs */
    max-width: 747px; /* sets the max width of the container that all divs are contained in */ /* if this decreases */
}

.nav-menu {
    padding-inline-start: 0px; /* removes extra padding from the left side of the links in the footer */
}

.nav-menu li {
    list-style-type: none; /* removes the markers from the links organized as list items */
    display: inline; /* organizes the links horizontally not vertically */
}

.nav-menu a:link {
    color: #eeeeee; /* colors the links in the nav text */
    padding: 3px 4px 0px; /* adds padding to the TOP, RIGHT/LEFT, and BOTTOM */
    text-decoration: none; /* removes the underline from the links in the nav */
}

.nav-menu a:visited {
    color: #eeeeee; /* colors the links in the nav AFTER they have been visited before */
}

.nav-menu a:hover {
    color: #32e0c4; /* colors the links in the nav text */
}

#main {
    top: 300px; /* centers the masthead by pushing it down */
    left: 0; /* stretches the main across the screen by removing space from the left side */
    right: 0; /* stretches the main across the screen by removing space from the right side */
}

#main-container {
    margin: 0 auto; /* adds margins to both sides of the div, centers the div containing all the other divs */
    max-width: 747px; /* makes the search bar as long as the masthead */
}

h1 {
    color: #fa1616; /* colors the Masthead */
    font-size: 131px; /* controls the size of the masthead */
    text-align: center; /* centers the masthead in its div */
    word-wrap: break-word; /* allows long words to break and go to the next line instead of stretching beyond the div */
}

form input[type=text] { /* combines the form w/ the input field */
    padding: 20px 10px; /* increases the size of the form */
    font-size: 17px; /* increases the size of the text within the input field */
    border: 1px solid #f4f6ff;
    border-radius: 25px; /* rounds the edges of the input field */
    background: #f1f1f1; /* adds a color to the form */
    text-align: center; /* centers the input field in the surrounding form */
    width: 97%; /* controls the size of the form */
}

input:focus, textarea:focus {
    outline: 0; /* removes the highlight from the form */
}

#footer {
    background-color: #222831; /* colors the background of the footer section */
    text-align: center; /* centers the text in each div within the footer */
    right: 0; /* stretches the footer across the screen by removing space from the right side */
    bottom: 0; /* keeps the footer at the bottom of the page */
    left: 0; /* stretches the footer across the screen by removing space from the left side */
}

#footer-container {
    margin: 0 auto; /* adds margins to both sides of the div, centers the div containing all the other divs */
    max-width: 747px; /* sets the max width of the container that all divs are contained in */ /* if this decreases */
}

.footer-row {
    padding-inline-start: 0px; /* removes extra padding from the left side of the links in the footer */
}

.footer-row li {
    display: inline; /* organizes the list items horizontally not vertically */
    list-style-type: none; /* removes the dot from the list items */
}

.footer-row a:link { 
    color: #eeeeee; /* changes the color of the link in ALL stages */
    font-size: 15px; /* the font-size for the links is set to 15px */
    padding: 3px 4px 0px; /* adds padding to the TOP, RIGHT/LEFT, and BOTTOM */
    text-decoration: none; /* removes the underline from the links */
}

.footer-row a:visited {
    color:#eeeeee; /* changes the color of the link in ALL stages */
    font-size: 15px; /* the font-size for the links is set to 15px */
    padding: 3px 4px 0px; /* adds padding to the TOP, RIGHT/LEFT, and BOTTOM */
    text-decoration: none; /* removes the underline from the links */
}

.footer-row a:active { 
    color: #eeeeee; /* changes the color of the link in ALL stages */
    font-size: 15px; /* the font-size for the links is set to 15px */
    padding: 3px 4px 0px; /* adds padding to the TOP, RIGHT/LEFT, and BOTTOM */
    text-decoration: none; /* removes the underline from the links */
}

.footer-row a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline; /* restores the underline to links when hovered over */
}

#copyright {
    color:#eeeeee; /* colors the footer text */
    font-size: 13px; /* the font size of the copyright text is '13' */
}

/************************************************************************************************************/

/* Media Queries */

/* (1) 1440p Screen */

@media only screen and (max-width: 1440px) {

    #nav-container {
        max-width: 563px; /* contains the elements of the nav */
    }

    #main {
        top: 300px; /* centers the masthead by pushing it down */
    }

    #main-container {
        max-width: 563px; /* contains the elements of the main */
    }

    h1 {
        color: red;
        font-size: 108px; /* resizes the masthead */
        margin-top: 0px; /* removes the margin from the top of the masthead */
    }

    #footer-container {
        max-width: 563px; /* contains the elements of the footer */
    }

    .footer-row {
        padding: 0px 16px; /* adds padding to the sides of the links in the footer */
    }

    .footer-row a:link {
        padding: 0px; /* removes the padding from around the links */
    }

    #copyright {
        margin: 16px 0px; /* increases the margins around the copyright from 13px to 16px to match the margins of the rows above it */
    }
}

/* (2) 1080p Screen */

@media only screen and (max-width: 1080px) {

    #main {
        top: 300px; /* centers the masthead by pushing it down */
        left: 30px; /* centers the main by adding space to the left side */
        right: 30px; /* centers the main by adding space to the right side */
    }

    h1 {
        color: purple;
        font-size: 108px; /* resizes the masthead */
    }

    form input[type=text] {
        width: 96%; /* controls the size of the form */
    }

    #footer-container {
        margin: 0 auto; /* adds margins to both sides of the div, centers the div containing all the other divs */
    }

    .footer-row {
        padding: 0px 16px; /* adds padding to the sides of the links in the footer */
    }

    .footer-row a:link {
        padding: 0px; /* removes the padding from around the links */
    }

    #copyright {
        margin: 16px 0px; /* increases the margins around the copyright from 13px to 16px to match the margins of the rows above it */
    }
}

/* (3) iPad Pro */

@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {

    #main {
        top: 450px; /* centers the masthead by pushing it down */
        left: 30px; /* centers the main by adding space to the left side */
        right: 30px; /* centers the main by adding space to the right side */
    }

    h1 {
        color: yellow;
        font-size: 108px; /* resizes the masthead */
    }

    form input[type=text] {
        width: 96%; /* controls the size of the form */
    }

    #footer-container {
        margin: 0 auto; /* adds margins to both sides of the div, centers the div containing all the other divs */
    }

    .footer-row {
        padding: 0px 16px; /* adds padding to the sides of the links in the footer */
    }

    .footer-row a:link {
        padding: 0px; /* removes the padding from around the links */
    }

    #copyright {
        margin: 16px 0px; /* increases the margins around the copyright from 13px to 16px to match the margins of the rows above it */
    }
}

/* (4) iPad */

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    
    .nav-menu {
        padding-right: 16px; /* adds padding on the right side of the links in the nav */
    }

    #main {
        top: 300px; /* centers the masthead by pushing it down */
        left: 30px; /* centers the main by adding space to the left side */
        right: 30px; /* centers the main by adding space to the right side */
    }

    h1 {
        color: brown;
        font-size: 108px; /* resizes the masthead */
    }

    form input[type=text] {
        width: 96%; /* controls the size of the form */
    }

    #footer-container {
        margin: 0 auto; /* adds margins to both sides of the div, centers the div containing all the other divs */
        max-width: 747px; /* sets the max width of the container that all divs are contained in */ /* if this decreases */
    }

    .footer-row {
        padding: 0px 16px; /* adds padding to the sides of the links in the footer */
    }

    .footer-row a:link {
        padding: 0px; /* removes the padding from around the links */
    }

    #copyright {
        margin: 16px 0px; /* increases the margins around the copyright from 13px to 16px to match the margins of the rows above it */
    } 
}

/* (5) iPhone 6/7/8 Plus */

@media only screen and (max-width: 414px) {

    #main {
        top: 220px; /* centers the masthead by pushing it down */
    }

    h1 {
        color: yellow;
        font-size: 58px; /* resizes the masthead */
    }

    form input[type=text] {
        width: 77%; /* controls the size of the form */
    }

    input {
        margin-left: 30px; /* adds margins to the left side of the search bar */
    }

    #footer-container {
        margin: 0px; /* adds margins to both sides of the div, centers the div containing all the other divs */
        max-width: 747px; /* sets the max width of the container that all divs are contained in */ /* if this decreases */
    }

    .footer-row {
        padding: 0px 16px; /* adds padding to the sides of the links in the footer */
    }

    .footer-row a:link {
        padding: 0px; /* optional: removes the padding from around the links */
    }

    #copyright {
        margin: 16px 0px; /* increases the margins around the copyright from 13px to 16px to match the margins of the rows above it */
    }
}

/* (6) Pixel 2 */ /* Pixel 2 XL */

@media only screen and (max-width: 411px) {

    .nav-menu {
        padding-right: 16px; /* adds padding on the right side of the links in the nav */
    }

    #main {
        top: 230px; /* centers the masthead by pushing it down */
    }

    h1 {
        color: blue;
        font-size: 58px; /* resizes the masthead */
        margin-top: 0px; /* removes the margin above the masthead */
    }

    form input[type=text] {
        width: 77%; /* controls the size of the form */
    }

    #footer-container {
        margin: 0px; /* adds margins to both sides of the div, centers the div containing all the other divs */
        max-width: 747px; /* sets the max width of the container that all divs are contained in */ /* if this decreases */
    }

    .footer-row {
        padding: 0px 16px; /* adds padding to the sides of the links in the footer */
    }

    #copyright {
        margin: 16px 0px; /* increases the margins around the copyright from 13px to 16px to match the margins of the rows above it */
    }
}

/* (7) iPhone 6/7/8 */ /* iPhone X */

@media only screen and (max-width: 375px) {

    .nav-menu {
        padding-right: 16px; /* adds padding on the right side of the links in the nav */
    }

    #main {
        top: 185px; /* centers the masthead by pushing it down */
    }

    h1 {
        color: brown;
        font-size: 58px; /* resizes the masthead */
        margin-top: 0px; /* removes the margin above the masthead */
    }

    form input[type=text] {
        width: 88%; /* controls the size of the form */
    }

    input {
        margin-left: 10px; /* adds margins to the left side of the search bar */
    }

    #footer-container {
        margin: 0px; /* adds margins to both sides of the div, centers the div containing all the other divs */
        max-width: 747px; /* sets the max width of the container that all divs are contained in */ /* if this decreases */
    }

    .footer-row {
        padding: 0px 16px; /* adds padding to the sides of the links in the footer */
    }

    #copyright {
        margin: 16px 0px; /* increases the margins around the copyright from 13px to 16px to match the margins of the rows above it */
    }
}

/* (8) Moto G4 */ /* Galaxy S5 */

@media only screen and (max-width: 360px) {

    .nav-menu {
        padding-right: 16px; /* adds padding on the right side of the links in the nav */
    }

    #main {
        top: 175px; /* centers the masthead by pushing it down */
    }

    h1 {
        color: green;
        font-size: 55px; /* resizes the masthead */
    }

    form input[type=text] {
        width: 87%; /* controls the size of the form */
    }

    #footer-container {
        margin: 0px; /* adds margins to both sides of the div, centers the div containing all the other divs */
        max-width: 747px; /* sets the max width of the container that all divs are contained in */ /* if this decreases */
    }

    .footer-row {
        padding: 0px 16px; /* adds padding to the sides of the links in the footer */
    }

    #copyright {
        margin: 16px 0px; /* increases the margins around the copyright from 13px to 16px to match the margins of the rows above it */
    }
}

/* (9) iPhone 5/SE */

@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {

    #nav-container {
        margin-right: 0px; /* adds margins to the right side of the nav div */
    }

    .nav-menu {
        padding-right: 16px; /* adds padding on the right side of the links in the nav */
    }

    #main {
        top: 150px; /* centers the masthead by pushing it down */
    }

    h1 {
        color: pink;
        font-size: 50px; /* resizes the masthead */
    }

    form input[type=text] {
        width: 93%; /* controls the size of the form */
    }

    input {
        margin-left: 0px; /* removes the margin from the left side of the input field */
    }

    #footer-container {
        margin: 0px; /* adds margins to both sides of the div, centers the div containing all the other divs */
        max-width: 747px; /* sets the max width of the container that all divs are contained in */ /* if this decreases */
    }

    .footer-row {
        padding: 0px 16px; /* adds padding to the sides of the links in the footer */
    }

    #copyright {
        margin: 16px 0px; /* increases the margins around the copyright from 13px to 16px to match the margins of the rows above it */
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <title></title>
            <link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">
        </head>
        
        <body>

            <div id="nav">
                <div id="nav-container">
                    <ul class="nav-menu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="">Sign Up</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="">Log In</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="main">
                <div id="main-container">
                    
                    <div id="main-row-1">
                        <h1>MASTHEAD</h1>
                    </div>

                    <div id="main-row-2">
                        <form class="example" action="">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Search">
                          </form>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="footer">
                <div id="footer-container">

                    <!-- row 1 -->
                    <ul class="footer-row">
                        <li>
                            <a href="pages/btd_pages/a.html" style="text-transform: none;">Browse the Dictionary:</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="pages/btd_pages/a.html">a</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="pages/btd_pages/b.html">b</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="pages/btd_pages/c.html">c</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="pages/btd_pages/d.html">d</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="pages/btd_pages/e.html">e</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="pages/btd_pages/f.html">f</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="pages/btd_pages/g.html">g</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="pages/btd_pages/h.html">h</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="pages/btd_pages/i.html">i</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="pages/btd_pages/j.html">j</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="pages/btd_pages/k.html">k</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="pages/btd_pages/l.html">l</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="pages/btd_pages/m.html">m</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="pages/btd_pages/n.html">n</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="pages/btd_pages/o.html">o</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="pages/btd_pages/p.html">p</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="pages/btd_pages/q.html">q</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="pages/btd_pages/r.html">r</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="pages/btd_pages/s.html">s</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="pages/btd_pages/t.html">t</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="pages/btd_pages/u.html">u</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="pages/btd_pages/v.html">v</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="pages/btd_pages/w.html">w</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="pages/btd_pages/x.html">x</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="pages/btd_pages/y.html">y</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="pages/btd_pages/z.html">z</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                    <!-- row 2 -->
                    <ul class="footer-row">
                        <li>
                            <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="pages/about_us.html">About Us</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="pages/contact_us.html">Contact Us</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="pages/terms_of_use.html">Disclaimer</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                    <!-- row 3 -->
                    <div class="footer-row">
                        <p id="copyright">&copy; 2020 Copyright</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <script src="js/script.js"></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I guess you are trying to do this all manually for the learning experience but have you ever taken a look at bootstrap? It is very simple to use and has responsiveness built in!

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/

Comment: Consider using semantic HTML tags rather than `div` for everything. For instance, there is a `<footer>` tag you could use rather than `<div id="footer">` that adds more meaning to the structure. Ditto with `<main>`, `<nav>`, and possibly `<header>`. It won't help with responsiveness, but will make the code easier to read.

Comment: Ah makes sense. When you say it adds more meaning to the structure, do you mean the browser treats them differently?

Comment: I know bootstrap, but I need the practice w/ regular CSS.